# Google extensible service proxy ESV_V2 support for AppCheck: X-Firebase-AppCheck

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-security, firebase-app-check

I was looking into ESP_V2 Support for [OpenAPI features](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-esp-v2-startup-options) and did not see any integration with [AppCheck header: X-Firebase-AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/custom-resource). Does anyone know, is this possible to integrated with ESP_v2, otherwise I would have to validate AppCheck Token in my backend endpoint behind the proxy.

Thank you